Slow scrolling in paging3 load function
I'm encountering slow loading as I scroll because of multiple network calls that need to be made.
class RepoResultPagingSource(
private val repository: Repository,
private val query: String
) : PagingSource<Int, Result>() {

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Result> {
    try {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        // network call to get repositories
        val repos = repository.getRepositories(query, page, PAGE_SIZE)

        val results = repos.map { repo ->
            // uses repo to get its top contributor
            val contributor = repository.getTopContributor(repo.owner.username, repo.reponame)
            Result(repo.owner.url, repo.reponame, contributor.username?: "")
        }
        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = repoResults,
            prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page-1,
            nextKey = page + 1
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}

class Repository(private val api: RepositoryApi,
             private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) {
    suspend fun getRepositories(query: String, page: Int, perPage: Int): List<Repository> 
    {
       return withContext(dispatcher) {
           api.search(query, page, perPage).repositories
       }
    }

    suspend fun getTopContributor(ownerName: String, repoName: String): Contributor {
        return withContext(dispatcher) {
            api.getContributors(ownerName, repoName, 1).first()
        }
    }
}

I realized that load was blocking because the paging library calls it from runBlockin
@JvmStatic
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)
    public fun <K : Any, T : Any> create(
        pagingSource: PagingSource<K, T>,
        initialPage: PagingSource.LoadResult.Page<K, T>?,
        coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
        notifyDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
        fetchDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
        boundaryCallback: BoundaryCallback<T>?,
        config: Config,
        key: K?
    ): PagedList<T> {
        val resolvedInitialPage = when (initialPage) {
            null -> {
                // Compatibility codepath - perform the initial load immediately, since caller
                // hasn't done it. We block in this case, but it's only used in the legacy path.
                val params = PagingSource.LoadParams.Refresh(
                    key,
                    config.initialLoadSizeHint,
                    config.enablePlaceholders,
                )
                runBlocking {
                    val initialResult = pagingSource.load(params)
                    when (initialResult) {
                        is PagingSource.LoadResult.Page -> initialResult
                        is PagingSource.LoadResult.Error -> throw initialResult.throwable
                        is PagingSource.LoadResult.Invalid ->
                            throw IllegalStateException(
                                "Failed to create PagedList. The provided PagingSource " +
                                    "returned LoadResult.Invalid, but a LoadResult.Page was " +
                                    "expected. To use a PagingSource which supports " +
                                    "invalidation, use a PagedList builder that accepts a " +
                                    "factory method for PagingSource or DataSource.Factory, " +
                                    "such as LivePagedList."
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            else -> initialPage
        }
        return ContiguousPagedList(
            pagingSource,
            coroutineScope,
            notifyDispatcher,
            fetchDispatcher,
            boundaryCallback,
            config,
            resolvedInitialPage,
            key
        )
    }

So I inject a viewModelScope to start a nonblocking coroutine like
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Result> {
    try {
        return scope.async {
            val page = params.key ?: 1
            // network call to get repositories
            val repos = repository.getRepositories(query, page, 10)

            val results = repos.map { repo ->
                // uses repo to get its top contributor
                val contributor = repository.getTopContributor(repo.owner.username, 
repo.reponame)
                Result(repo.owner.url, repo.reponame, contributor.username?: "")
            }
            return@async LoadResult.Page(
                data = repoResults,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page-1,
                nextKey = page + 1
            )
       }.await() as LoadResult<Int, Result>
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}

Unfortunately scroll remains slow, so I ask
1.Is it true that load by default runs in a blocking fashion, despite getRepositories and getTopContributor switch to Dispatchers.IO, according to Why 'withContext' does not switch coroutines under 'runBlocking'? it is
2.Since I need to make 1 network request to get repos, and each of those repos need to find their top contributor I am making page_size+1 requests.  I'm looking for tips to improve my scroll performance as each page relies on these network requests.  My Pager looks like
val pagingData: Flow<PagingData<RepoResult>> = Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(pageSize = PAGE_SIZE, prefetchDistance = 4 * PAGE_SIZE),
    pagingSourceFactory = { RepoResultPagingSource(repo, QUERY, viewModelScope) }
).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)


Unfortunately I can't write a comment.
Have you tried running it in a release build?
I had about the same problem with the debug build, there was also a lag during swapping. I searched for the problem for a long time, put together a release build - and everything is fine!
